# Why Does my Form Try to Dispose When Accessing ListBox.SelectedItem.ToString()?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, dispose

I'm developing a small POS for a university project.
I have a form which acts as a POS main window, with a datagrid and so on. Also, I have one form who is the Sensitive search or Incremental search, and I want that form to, select one item in a listbox and return it to the main window. Now I have a property in the main which gets that item as a string, and when the user clicks the OK button on the search form, I want to set that property on the main window.

Everything works great except one thing: when I try to access `listBox_Codigo.SelectedItem.ToString();`
the app tries to dispose and closes all windows...
Does anybody know why?

I just need the selected string in that listbox and set it to the main window like this:

```
var Principal = (PDQ.Cajero)this.ParentForm;
                Principal.CodigoInsertado = listBox_Codigo.SelectedItem.ToString();
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                this.Close();
```

where `PDQ.Cajero` is the main form, which calls this form.

UPDATE: I just finished debugging it, and right after the program gets to
`listBox_Codigo.SelectedItem.ToString();`
the program jumps to `Dispose()`.

**UPDATE 2**
This is my complete method:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox_Codigo.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show(this, "No se puede ingresar un producto sin seleccionarlo.\n ¿Desea intentarlo de nuevo, o Salir?", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
                this.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var Principal = (PDQ.Cajero)this.ParentForm;
            Principal.CodigoInsertado = listBox_Codigo.SelectedItem.ToString();
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            this.Close();

        }
    }
```

So the problem is not if the value is null...

Comment: Updated the question. It can't be null because I already checked in the code

Comment: Given the code, is Principal null?

Comment: nop. Principal is not null looks like...

Comment: Even with an accepted answer you should still review your exception handling practices.  If you were catching exceptions, you likely wouldn't have seen the form disposing.  @kubal5003 made a valid comment with respect to Debug-> Exceptions and breaking on all unhandled exceptions.  In production, your app **will** fail for reasons you don't think of; in these instances, graceful exception handling and logging will help you keep your sanity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There likely *is* no `SelectedItem` (meaning that the value of the property is `null`). In this case your code is throwing a `NullReferenceException`, since you can't call a function on a `null` reference. Because you aren't catching it, the application is catching it at a higher level an attempting to exit. This is what's calling your `Dispose` method.

Comment: Oh Okay. Looks like this fix it... Sorry for not seeing it at first... Thanks Guys

Comment: If this fixed your problem I'd appreciate it being marked as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the form is disposing because you aren't handling a `NullReferenceException`.

My general rule of thumb for exception handling in GUIs is to have a try-catch block in all the event handlers that logs the exception to a file and notifies the user of an error.

What do you get with this code?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (listBox_Codigo.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show(this, "No se puede ingresar un producto sin seleccionarlo.\n ¿Desea intentarlo de nuevo, o Salir?", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
                this.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var Principal = (PDQ.Cajero)this.ParentForm;
            Principal.CodigoInsertado = listBox_Codigo.SelectedItem.ToString();
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            this.Close();
        }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        //LogException(ex);
   }
}
```

Comment: Try catch blocks aren't for debugging purposes. Instead in VS you select Debug->Exceptions and make sure you see everything that is thrown.

Comment: They'll be necessary in production anyway so you might as well use them in development.

Comment: @kubal5003 If it is faster and/or easier to just wrap in a try/catch to find the error, why not use it (and then if you really don't want a try/catch remove after you find the issue?) Seems like a waste to ignore a tool that can save time and effort

Comment: Those that are in production are at carefully chosen places. Putting try-catch statements all over the code is the worst thing that you can do. It finally comes to a point that you can't debug anything, because of try-catch hell.

Comment: @Gordon Tucker
"and then if you really don't want(..._ remove afrer you find the issue"
One simple question: how many time have you done that? From my experience they always stay and then after let's say one month or half year you find that some @!@$@#%@#@ has left try-catch block and you've spent some hours trying to find out what was going on.

Comment: I think you missed my "event handler" clarification -- the reason I put them there is because it is the last line of defense in code I control (short of the UnhandledException event on AppDomain).  Used elsewhere in code, they should be used when necessary and with specific intent.